# using linq, update one node in an xml item

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-xml

Is there an easy way to update one node of an xml item?  I have this:

```
 <userlist>
  <users>
    <name>bob</name>
    <userid>1</userid>
  </users>
  <users>
   ...etc...
```

I need to update the name in userid #1.  I have this (hardcoded for clarity, not how it'll function):

```
XDocument userDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

var userList = from users in userDoc.Descendants("userlist")
                  where users.Element("userid").Value == "1"
                  select users;

foreach (XElement user in userList)
{
  user.SetElementValue("name", "Phil");
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx)**

```
        var firstUser = (from users in userDoc.Descendants("userlist")
                       where users.Element("userid").Value == "1"
                       select users).First();

        firstUser.SetElementValue("name", "Phil");
```

or

```
userDoc.Descendants("userlist").First( x => x.Element("userid").Value == "1" ).SetElementValue( "name", "Phil");
```